# How to sync email contacts between computers for use in mutt?

Tags: email, mutt, synchronization, offlineimap

I'm using mutt as email client. Specifically, this is my setup:

- Mail is stored at a remote hosting company.
- Mail is retrieved locally using OfflineIMAP.
- I have two mail accounts: one personal and one for work. Both use separate Maildirs/`muttrc`s/instances of mutt.

I've been using abook as address book and in general I like it. However, I'd like to have my contacts synced between computers. Apart from using Dropbox or similar software, is it possible to store the contacts somehow on the mail server?

I've read that for example Alpine uses the IMAP protocol to synchronize contacts. Is something similar possible for mutt/abook?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You definitely want to sync your contacts via CardDav (+calender via CalDav?). To sync up use vdirsyncer, it's basically the same what offlineimap is doing for mutt. `Khard` is a nice address book for your terminal which works with the synced up content. Of course you can combine mutt and khard to work together. If you speak German you probably want to have a look at [this](http://blog.ploth.xyz/blog/2017/10/31/dank-mutt-setup.html).